# PHP Login Script (Secure but not like a bank vault)

Tags: php, mysql, login-script

Looking for a php login script. I've searched stackoverflow and have seen a lot of posts, but can anyone recommend the best method? Also, If I want to use hashing, how do you decode the password when retrieving? My iPhone app uses the same database and currently the passwords are stored in normal text (not very secure, I know).

Also, if I implement a login page that redirects to info.php, how do you stop the user from going directly to the info.php page without logging in, Session control?

Look forward to hearing your input. Thanks very much.

Comment: THANKS to everyone for their responses. This is great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a great tutorial](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Building-a-CHAP-Login-System-An-ObjectOriented-Approach/) on login system design.  It covers all the major topics in an object oriented manner and is great for learning about the different considerations.

Decodable passwords are not as secure as they could be, but I've had clients insist that they be able to retrieve and change the password at will, no exceptions.  So in some cases I opted to salt a base64 encoded string to store in the database, and that seems to work pretty well.  A function exists to encode/decode as needed for the admin user.

Indeed, session control (and/or cookies) are the method to control access.  Building it with an object oriented pattern would allow you to do that with just a line or two of code per page (or a line in a header if it's common).

My one warning is to consider if you have a common login level or need user-level permissions.  It's significantly more work to decide after you've built the site that permissions-based logins are important.  It can become a real monster if not planned for in the beginning.

Comment: The linked example is **NOT secure**. The password hashing contains flaws and the example is vulnerable to SQL-injection as an added bonus.

Comment: @jacco, the OP didn't ask about SQL injection, they were looking for an example of a login script with decodable passwords.  It should go  without saying that a professional developer wouldn't skip basic security steps such as data sanitation, and you'd be foolish to use a public, free tutorial to protect your mission critical website.

Comment: As far as I read the question, he want's to do hashing and has no idea about the subject. Anyhow, you should never recommend any insecure code. This is even more true for a security related example. The example shows more insecure practices. In other words, it is not a good example, it promotes insecure practices and should not be followed, at all.

Answer (score 4):

Bit late for my answer, but i'll post anyway and i know this doesn't directly answer the question but it is related non the less. Here are a few points about login security.

**Remember Me**

You are best to re-hash the hashed password, and store the rehash in the cookie used to automatically log the user in. When you rehash the password, use something specific to the browser as a seed such as the browser type. This will help prevent the cookie being stolen (via people snooping on the network traffic). This helps prevent any chance of using rainbow tables.

**Sessions**

Be aware of session hijacking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

**CSRF**

Cross Site Request Forgery - Implemented after you login, but something to be aware of since it only affects logged in members: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

**HTTPS**

HTTPS should be used on the page the login request is being sent to - it does NOT have to be on the page you are typing your login details on!

**Hashing**

You can hash a password client side using javascript which would only server to protect members from having their passwords stolen while transfering them over the network when not using HTTPS. This is good because many people often use the same password for many sites. The disadvantages are: you can't check password length server side & they can't loggin if javascript is disabled (though you can program around that to a degree). Yahoo used to (might still do) do this years ago.

When you recieve the password on the server it is often rehashed using a seed and stored in the database. This is more secure as even if people know the hash, they still can't login! Only the original password will rehash to the same hash letting the user login.

**Keyloggers**

If you want to get around keyloggers (or most of them) you can do so by adding a JavaScript keypad / keyboard. The user then clicks the letters and numbers to enter their password using the mouse instead of the keyboard meaning the keylogger has a hard time logging the password.

**Know Something, Has Something, Is Something**

The three levels of security. Something someone knows such as a password, something someone has such as a phone (google completes these first 2 using 2 step verification), and something someone is such as a finger print. The more of these you fullfill the greater your security credentials are - by a long shot!!!

**Bots**

Computers sometimes try to brute force a fast login page (must be fast as if the password is incorrect and the script pauses for even just 1 second, that greatly reduces the total login attempts a bot can make. To help stop this you can either pause an incorrect login for 1 or 2 seconds (like linux does) or you can produce a capture that bots have a hard time solving after X incorrect logins (like google does).

There the main points, but i'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 3):

POST to a HTTPS URL.

You never decode the hashed password. Lost passwords need another mechanism to handle.

Yes, session control. Set a flag in the session on login and check for it on the other pages.

Answer (score 3):

Still under development, but secure, fast, clean, good and up-to-date:

[up to date version] https://github.com/Panique/PHP-Login

[old version's website] http://www.php-login.net

I've created this with some designer & coder help. It has been discussed in several forums and got very positive replies. All current issues can be seen on the github issue page. All code is public, free and forkable.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to decode the password, you will have to store the hashed password in your database, and when the user tries to login, you compare the stored password with the hash of the entered password.

About info.php, yes, if login succeeds you assign a variable in your session, and to test if the user is logged, you just test if that variable is assigned or not.

Answer (score 2):

basically you hash your password so it cannot be retrieved for malicious purpose, the hash is stored in the database instead of the password in clear text, you only compare the 2 hash values.

your client can store the password as they want, but the web application should control at each step the session validity (store some logged in identifier in the session variables with proper expiration or something like that),
so basically you `require("session_control.inc")` in every "protected" page so you could check for the session validity.

The best course would be to use an MVC framework which could help in defining the logic in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use password hashing but there is also php's crypt() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

They essentially do the same thing but crypt is a little neater IMO. Make sure you also get a good salt generation script so when you save the password in the database here is my password encryption function, notice this isn't that secure without the salt function

```
function crypt_password($password)
{
    if($password){
        //blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 base 64
        $blowfish = '$2a$10$';

        //get the random bytes and makes a salt
        $salt = $this->get_salt();

        //append salt2 data to the password, and crypt using salt, results in a 60 char output
        $crypt_pass = crypt($password,$blowfish . $salt);

        //blowfish comes out as 60, check
        $len = strlen($crypt_pass);

        if($len == 60)
        {
            return $crypt_pass;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception('encryption failed');
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception('encryption failed, missing password');
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then when you want to verify this password you simply query the database for the login email or user id then to verify its as simple as

```
if (crypt($input_pass, $stored_pass) == $stored_pass) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is your $this in the above example ??

Comment: @james a function that generates a random salt its a modification of http://www.openwall.com/phpass/